# very weird error with php script in Xcode

Tags: php, xcode

I have heaps of scripts in my xcode project where I get stuff from a mysql database... but i've come across this very weird problem.. on the first page of the app, I can't get the output from the php script without making a line break in the middle of everything...

here is my code:

```
    <?php
    include("connect.php");

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    ?>

    <?

    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lande WHERE id = '$id'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {

     $navn = $row['name'];

     echo$navn;

    }

    ?>
```

It makes no sense.. it works in all of the others queries...

I find the id of the country:

```
      NSString *strUrl2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:xxxx/xxxx/frontpage.php"];

      NSData *dataURL2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl2]];

      NSString *strResult2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And then send it to next page through $_GET:

```
        NSString *strUrl1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:xxxx/xxxx/frontpage2.php?id=%@", strResult2];

        NSData *dataURL1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl1]];

        NSString *strResult1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%@", strResult1);
```

But it requires me to make this line break in the middle of the frontpage script:

```
     $id = $_GET['id'];

     ?>

     <?

     $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lande WHERE id = '$id'");
```

else it wont output it...

EDIT: I've tried to send another variable through $_GET to frontpage.php, and it works perfectly!! What is wrong with strResult1??

Appreciate all kinds of help!

Comment: @MihaiIorga : Thanks for that information, I deleted my answer